# VSC Updated and Broke Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I think two weeks ago, or right at the end of Feburary, VSC updated as normal. Except, in my experience, it broke the Jupyter Notebook extension, kind of. I can still open notebooks and play with them, they still connect to the kernel and run, but I can't save any new notebooks. Which is frustrating because I need to make new notebooks for my classes.

First, I'll say that I have tried to update and reinstall jupyter. By that, I mean:
pip install --upgrade notebook
pip install --upgrade jupyterlab
pip install --upgrade jupyter

Then I uninstalled VSC, and reinstalled to see if that would fix it, but the problem remains.

Here are detailed pictures of what my issue is.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

1. I open a new file, and go to select language
2. Inside the languages, jupyter isn't even there
3. Instead I go down to open the command palette because thats where you have to open new jupyter notebooks anyway
4. Here you can see it says create new notebook
5. It does, it works as its supposed to
6. Then I go to save the notebook and this is totally new. It's saving it as JSON, but has the ipynb extension. Additionally, the directory I'm saving into has other notebooks in it. They don't show up with this new .ipynb.json.
7. It doesn't matter if I erase, leave, force the extension to be .ipynb, .json, .ipynb.json, or if I just erase it, I get this same error, and I'm not sure why.

I can't seems to get over this problem, and I'm not sure how to fix it. Let alone, what's caused this issue. Maybe somebody has had this before and worked around it, or currently has this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your problem, Could you try to disable all the extensions and then only enable Python-related extensions? If it still does not work, could you try to install an older version of VSCode? You can refer to [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_64).

Comment: I don't even know how the problem originated, other than an updated VSC. I've disabled, and uninstalled all the jupyter stuff through VSC, reinstalled/enabled it. This doesn't seem to help. I thought about installing an older version, but figured this shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Change "save as type" to "All files (*.*)" if *.ipynb isn't a choice outright to make sure you get `*.ipynb` as the extension, not `*.ipynb.json`.

Comment: So, I have looked inside the "All files (.)" and even inside there, there no .ipynb alone. It does give me a list of other things to save as, but none of which are exclusively. Additionally, I can work on and save over old notebooks already, it's just a matter of creating and saving new ones. This issue still isn't worked out, so I have to make copies of old notebooks, then just erase the stuff in them.